# Add ClientID to a javascript GET request on Twitch Kraken API

Tags: javascript, api, get, twitch, clientid

I have JavaScript code that used to work fine, but now the twitch kraken API uses a Client ID parameter...
I have my client id setup already like the twitch dev tutorial, and it's working fine if I ask it manually by the browser, but in my script it doesn't work, it says:

> Bad Request

I didn't enter my client ID...

**My Code:**

```js
var channels = ["gabriel1375","kawayz","flxoficial"]
var channelsOnline = 0;
var cha = 0;

timerChannels();
function timerChannels(){
 $('.streamers').html("");
 channelsOnline = 0;
 for(var i=0; i<channels.length; i++) {
  $.get( "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/"+channels[i]+"?client_id=m9se7lg0twk3g1yoobohr2w2tnzmli", function( data ) {

  
  
  if(data.stream == null) {
   $("#streamoff").show();
  } else {
   setInterval(function() {
   $("#streamoff").hide();
   }, 100);
   $('.streamers').append('<div class="streamer" data-viewers="'+data.stream.viewers+'">\
   <img src="'+data.stream.channel.logo+'">\
   <div class="sname"><a href="http://twitch.tv/'+data.stream.channel.name+'" target="_blank">'+data.stream.channel.name+'</a></div>\
   <div class="viewers"><i class="fa fa-circle-o online"></i> <b>'+data.stream.viewers+'</b> viewers, playing <b>'+data.stream.game+'</b></div>\
   </div>');
  }
  });
  
  channelsOnline++;
 }
}

setInterval(function() {
 console.log('Loaded twitch script');
 timerChannels();
}, 30000);
```

Why it didn't works ??? Thanks !!!
Also sorry for the code, i think i made it in the wrong section or something like that, im new in the stackoverflow !